# Getting error type/value when validating json schema with ajv

Tags: json, jsonschema, ajv

I'm trying to use json schema to validate the json of an api.

I've found the ajv library, which seems to be the most popular for node.js.

Just getting the basics, I've defined my schema as

```
const viewSchema = {
    "type": "object",
    "properties":{
        "title": {"type": "string"}
    }
}

export default viewSchema;
```

I then import it into my validator

```
import Ajv from 'ajv';

import viewSchema from './viewSchema';
const ajv = Ajv({allErrors: true});
let validate = ajv.compile(viewSchema);

const validateView = viewJson => {
    var isValid = validate(viewJson);
    console.log('------ text',ajv.errorsText(), isValid)
    if(isValid) return true;
    return ajv.errorsText();
}

export default validateView;
```

and using mocha (with mochaccino) test the output

```
describe('validate view', () => {
    it('should error if title is not a string', () => {
        console.log('-----------',validateView({"title":122}))
        expect(validateView({"title":122}).errors).toContain('should be string');
    });
});
```

following the directions from the [ajv github page](https://github.com/epoberezkin/ajv) I expect my test to fail as the type required is a string and I've provided a number. But the response I'm getting from `ajv.errorsText()` is `No Errors` where it should provide an error.

Seems so simple, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to pass errors to `ajv.errorsText()`:

```
ajv.errorsText(validate.errors)
```

Without parameter it would return errors text if you use method `ajv.validate`.

See https://github.com/epoberezkin/ajv#errorstextarrayobject-errors--object-options---string

Comment: Thanks, the main documentation says `if (!valid) console.log(ajv.errorsText());` so I was going with that.

Comment: yes, in the case where it uses ajv.validate. Need to add errorsText to the previous example.